# Algebra non-routine problem book reommendation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a high school teacher and I'd like a recommendation for a source, or book of non-routine (exam, test) problems, requiring only algebra skills to solve. The more thought provoking the problems are the better.

Thank you!

Comment: I highly recommend the following book https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algebra-Richard-Rusczyk/dp/1934124141/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1489713381&sr=8-2&keywords=art+of+problem+solving+algebra. You can also purchase the complete solution manual as well.

Comment: I would suggest looking at math competitions targeted to high school.  Things like http://www.math.sc.edu/contest/problems.

Comment: I think this is exactly the book you are looking for, Topics in Algebra and Analysis: Preparing for the Mathematical Olympiad. https://www.amazon.com/Topics-Algebra-Analysis-Preparing-Mathematical/dp/3319119451